# Mysql2 response does not work with method collect in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, unit-testing, collect

I am using mysql2 in my ruby script.
using this to test API responses against the mysql DB

this is a snippet of my script

```
test_job_by_id_5
 id = $data["jobs"]["id"][i] # example 5
 job = JobServices.job_by_id(id)
 response = @@con.query("select * from jobs where id = #{id}") #select * from jobs where id =5
 rs=response.collect #this fails
 assert_match(job[0]['title'],rs[0]['title'],"The title values are equal for #{$data["jobs"]["id"][i]}")
end
```

So when i use this with `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10]` it works like a charm

but when i use `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]` it does not work
i get this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for 
#<Enumerator: #<Mysql2::Result:0x00000012d19f18>:collect>
```

Can some one please help me fix this?

Comment: I'd first consider using single-quotes for your hash index strings inside the `assert_match` line, just for clarity.

Comment: I think i am using single quotes, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Maybe look at the last string again, "The title values..." Now do you know what I mean?

Comment: o that is because i want to pass a variable, may be i change all to double quotes :)

Comment: I'm saying use single quotes for the hash keys to make it easier to read. Don't gotta, but IMO it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `collect` on an `Enumerable` (which [`Mysql2::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/mysql2/Mysql2/Result) is), you get an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) instance back. `Enumerator`s don't implement the array access operator so you can't say `enumerator[0]` and get anything useful to happen; however, `Enumerator` does include `Enumerable` so they do respond to [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) so you probably want to do this:

```
rs  = response.collect
row = rs.first
assert_match(job[0]['title'], row['title'], "The title values are equal for #{$data["jobs"]["id"][i]}")
```

Or just skip the `Enumerator` entirely and call `first` on the `response`:

```
row = response.first
assert_match(job[0]['title'], row['title'], "The title values are equal for #{$data["jobs"]["id"][i]}")
```

or even this:

```
row = @@con.query("select * from jobs where id = #{id}").first
assert_match(job[0]['title'], row['title'], "The title values are equal for #{$data["jobs"]["id"][i]}")
```

Keep in mind that `row.nil?` will be true if your query doesn't find anything so you might want to take that into account if you don't want an exception.

Comment: thanks for the response, this will probably do it, but i need to iterate over all rows returned, and i do not know how many rows will be returned? Using `each`, but instead of doing `each` on the DB response I need to do it for each API response. So I am not sure if there is a `second` and `third`

Comment: @perlnewbie: I'm not sure what you mean but maybe you can turn it inside-out or fetch all the results into an array and then iterate `job` and that array concurrently.

Comment: I mean if i do `response[0]['title']` without using collect it does not work. So basically cannot iterate job and response in the same loop if I do `job.each do |i| assert_match(job[i]['title'],response[i]['title']) end`

Comment: But you can do `response.each { ... }` or `response.each_with_index { ... }` to iterate both at once.

Comment: yes, but I need to check for all values of `Job` and not all values of `response`. More like left join as compared to inner join in sql.

Comment: i think i also tried adding this `rs=response.collect { |a| a }` and now the collect works. but this seems like a very very  bad way to do it. Marking your response as a solution as I see where u were trying to get at. Thanks for ur replies, much appreciated. Also if you can think of a better way other than attaching `{ |a| a }` after `collect' that would be super!

Comment: If you supply the block for `Enumerable#collect`, you get an array out the other side, this can be expensive if the result set is large but it might not be worth worrying about in a test suite. [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) might be a good choice: `response.each_with_index { |r, i| assert_match(job[i]['title'], r[i], ...) }`.